# Is there a way to send a message as the user logged-in using discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am building a desktop application, and I need to send a message through it, that would be posted from the logged user's discord account. is there any way to do this? I know about webhooks and on_message bot-event.

Comment: you want to send the message via the discord pc client?

Comment: Sure if there is a way to do so.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this in discord.py, but you can in older versions of the nodejs version by simply passing the user's token instead of the bot token